# Django - "fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']" stops working after I add request return render html to function

Tags: html, django, request, return, render

```
def count(request):
    fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']
    return render(request, 'count.html')
```

fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']

would stop working after I added

```
return render(request, 'count.html')
```

to the function.

If I don't add the return render, it would give me ValueError:

Exception Value:
The view wordcount.views.count didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import operator
import string


    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html', )
    def count(request):
        fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']
    def about(request):
        return render(request, 'about.html',)


        #Deletes empty spaces in fulltext and save it as wordlist
        wordlist = fulltext.split()

        #Declare an empty list
        worddictionary = {}

        #For each word in wordlist, if exist in list add 1, if not, add it to list
        for word in wordlist:
            word = word.lower()
            if word in worddictionary:
                worddictionary[word] += 1
            else:
                worddictionary[word] = 1

        #Sort list from highest occurence to least
        sortedwords = sorted(worddictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

        return render(request, 'count.html',{'fulltext':fulltext,
        'count':len(wordlist), 'sortedwords': sortedwords})
```

Comment: is it the actual view which is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def count(request):
        fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']


        #Deletes empty spaces in fulltext and save it as wordlist
        wordlist = fulltext.split()

        #Declare an empty list
        worddictionary = {}

        #For each word in wordlist, if exist in list add 1, if not, add it to list
        for word in wordlist:
            word = word.lower()
            if word in worddictionary:
                worddictionary[word] += 1
            else:
                worddictionary[word] = 1

        #Sort list from highest occurence to least
        sortedwords = sorted(worddictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']
return render(request, 'count.html', {'fulltext': fulltext})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately it's still not working

Comment: Try an updated one. If error then mentions which error throws.

Comment: TypeError at /count/ , Exception Value: 
'QueryDict' object is not callable

Comment: Try again. I made a small mistake

Comment: Nice it worked! But, only {{fulltext}} is working .

Comment: you return only `fulltext` on context. Which value you want to pass?

Comment: I only want to get the fulltext, so I can use it for like wordlist = fulltext.split() and use that for to make a word dictionary. Do I have to add wordlist and others too?

Comment: Now it's saying NameError, wordlist is not defined. I did "return render(request, 'count.html',{'fulltext':fulltext,'count':len(wordlist), 'sortedwords': sortedwords})" at  the bottom of my code before I added your code.

Comment: Do you have any value in `wordlist`? You need to define `wordlist` before `return render...` like `wordlist=['value1', 'value2']`

Comment: Yes, I put wordlist = fulltext.split() but that's after I put       "def count(request):
  
    return render(request, 'count.html', {'fulltext': fulltext})'

Comment: Is any value here ` request.GET['fulltext'] `

Comment: Upon clicking a button, it gets the user's text and saves to fulltext other than that it didn't store any value.

Comment: I can;t understand. Is `fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']` fulltext has value or not?

Comment: Yes it has value

Comment: give the value you get.'

Comment: It's a quote from shakespeare, "By the pricking of my thumbs, Something wicked this way comes. Open, locks, Whoever knocks!
Fair is foul, and foul is fair: Hover through the fog and filthy air..."

Comment: I tried "return render(request, 'count.html')" to "def count(request):" I added my views.py code

Comment: Your code is full of bugs. Some method missing return statement. SOme method has one more return statement.

Comment: I'm following an online lecture , I should go back to the beginning of the lecture and see where it went wrong.

Comment: Okay I'm dumb,  I didn't know the views.py is a long list of functions and I didn't put all those code under "def count(request):"